# Keras custom metric for model with multiple heads

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

[tensorflow backend]

I've built a model multiple heads and it works well. By default the accuracy and loss for every head is calculated and printed separately.

```
Epoch 2/2
45000/45000 [==============================] - 35s - loss: 0.1403 - dense_14_loss: 0.0109 - dense_15_loss: 0.0208 - dense_16_loss: 0.0276 - dense_17_loss: 0.0372 - dense_18_loss: 0.0438 - dense_14_acc: 0.9965 - dense_15_acc: 0.9937 - dense_16_acc: 0.9914 - dense_17_acc: 0.9882 - dense_18_acc: 0.9860 - val_loss: 0.2223 - val_dense_14_loss: 0.0155 - val_dense_15_loss: 0.0353 - val_dense_16_loss: 0.0469 - val_dense_17_loss: 0.0526 - val_dense_18_loss: 0.0720 - val_dense_14_acc: 0.9944 - val_dense_15_acc: 0.9886 - val_dense_16_acc: 0.9862 - val_dense_17_acc: 0.9842 - val_dense_18_acc: 0.9802
```

Can I write a custom metric that combines the single metrics and for example calculates the average as a single metric? Would also be helpful for using callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can write a metric for multiple heads, but one way to accomplish what you want would be to get the return values of your `fit` method and add them together manually and print that result. If you want faster feedback you will have to use `train_on_batch` instead of `fit` and write your own output with this method.